# How to do a 301 redirect in Magento 1.7.0.2?

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

We recently change our old Eshop from aspx technology to Magento 1.7.0.2

**My old urls are like**

```
http://www.demostore.nl/Contact.aspx

http://www.demostore.nl/category1.aspx
```

**and now in magento are like**

```
http://www.demostore.nl/contacts

http://www.demostore.nl/products-category1
```

Could you give me some example of what and **how to include all my old urls with a 301** redirect to the new Magento site? I assume it will be inside **htaccess** but I dont know how exactly to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On


# catehory1.aspx => products-category1
RewriteRule ^(category[^.]*)\.aspx$ /products-$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# contact.aspx => contacts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.aspx$ /$1s [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.I assume that you suggest to put all of my old categories after this :  #RewriteBase /magento/  Is that correct ?

Comment: yes that's correct, try it out and if doesn't work let me know.

Comment: How would I transform http://www.demostore.nl/Home/demo.aspx  into http://www.demostore.nl/ ??? (without the index.php I mean... )

Comment: That will be **`RewriteRule ^Home/demo\.aspx$ / [L,R=301,NC]`**

Comment: As far as now it doesn't crash the site...stil one more question though. demostore.nl/wines.aspx into demostore.nl/demo-product-wines.html ???

Comment: That will be: **`RewriteRule ^wines\.aspx$ /demo-product-wines.html [L,R=301,NC]`**